# Retrieving projects without binary files

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

We have multiple very large perforce repositories with many binary files mixed in with source code.  Is it possible to configure a client spec so that certain file extensions (e.g. zip, jar, war, etc.) are never synced to the local copy?

We are syncing periodically to generate metrics on source code, and for this purpose the binary files just get in the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your client spec, use the "exclusionary" mappings, with a minus sign, as so:

```
View:
    //depot/project/... //client-name/project/...
    -//depot/project/.../*.zip //client-name/project/.../*.zip
    -//depot/project/.../*.jar //client-name/project/.../*.jar
    -//depot/project/.../*.war //client-name/project/.../*.war
```

Comment: To include files that are directly under the project root as well as any depth below it, remove the "/*" part (so it's just "project/....zip" etc).  This has the side benefit of being faster since it's fewer wildcards.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like *.[zip,jar,war] so that it can be done in one line instead of one line per file type (I've probably got 20 or so I'd want to exclude)?